# how to use treetagger in Node.js for morphological analysis

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm attempting to run treetagger by reference to https://www.npmjs.org/package/treetagger but I got the error below.

```
TypeError: Object function TreeTagger(options) {
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);
    this.options = options || {};
    this.encoding = this.options.encoding || 'latin-1';
    this.language = this.options.language || 'english';
    this.paths = ['.', '/usr/bin', '/usr/local/bin', '/opt/local/bin',
              '/Applications/bin', '~/bin', '~/Applications/bin'];
    this.envVars = ["TREETAGGER", "TREETAGGER_HOME"];

// Validate the given encoding and language selected
if (!this.encoding in languages) {
    throw new Error("Unsupported encoding detected " + this.encoding);
}
if (languages[this.encoding].indexOf(this.language) < 0) {
    throw new Error("Unsupported language detected " + this.language + " for encoding " + this.encoding);
}

// Set the appropriate bin path
if (this.encoding == "latin-1") {
    this.binPath = 'tree-tagger-' + this.language;
}
else {
    this.binPath = 'tree-tagger-' + this.language + '-' + this.encoding;
}

this.binPath = findPath(this.binPath, this.paths, this.envVars);
} has no method 'tag'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, there is an issue in the readme, it should be:

```
var TreeTagger = require('treetagger');
var tagger = new TreeTagger();
tagger.tag("This is a test!", function (err, results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

I sent a [**pull-request**](https://github.com/nyxtom/treetagger/pull/1/files) to the library author to fix this.